# Как посчитать скорость передачи данных?

Tags: передача-данных, данные, скорость

У меня передается 2048 байт за 0.002 секунды. Как посчитать скорость передачи данных в МБ/с?
Можно пример кода на Python?

Comment: А как в школе учили скорость считать?

Comment: Пример кода нужен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Язык программирования тут вообще не при чём.

```
2048 байт за 0.002 секунды.
```

Чтобы получить б/с нужно разделить:

```
2048б / 0.002с => 1024000 б/с
```

Дальше, чтобы получить килобайты нужно разделить на 1024, а чтобы получить мегабайты - ещё раз разделить на 1024:

```
1024000/1024/1024 => 0.9765625МБ/с
```

Там есть ещё тонкость в обозначениях, почему МБ, а не Мб. Обычно Мб обозначаются "мегаб**и**ты", а МБ - "мегаб**ай**ты".

Comment: Спасибо, я так и написал. Удивлен что скорость такая маленькая.

Comment: @Антон Ну если учебник старый, то тогда были модемы через телефонную сеть и это была недостижимая тогда скорость связи ))

Comment: @Антон на таких мизерных количествах вы промеряли не скорость передачи данных, а кучу накладных расходов на запуск измерения

Comment: @AlexeyTen можете подсказать тогда, как правильно померить скорость?

Comment: Очевидно передавать больше данных. Десятки мегабайт